# Loopback4 modifies filter parameter in repository 'findById' operation

Tags: typescript, loopback4

I'm trying here before going to create an issue as it might be simply my comprehension of how to use filters in LB4.

I'm using postgresql as a database within a lb4 application.
I made my controller, my models, and added the logic. I want my models to give back some relation in the response, so I created a default filter that will be used in a controller and repository :

```
const includedRelations = {
  include: [
    {
      relation: "licenseeloans",
      scope: {
        include: [
          {
            relation: "member"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      relation: "weaponloans"
    },
    {
      relation: "initiator"
    },
    {
      relation: "returnInitiator"
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is the controller part :

```
  console.log(includedRelations.include[0].scope)
  const newLoanWithRelation = await this.loanRepository.findById(newLoan.id, includedRelations);
  console.log(includedRelations.include[0].scope)
```

I found out that using this method give me this result:

```
{ include: [ { relation: 'member' } ] }
{ include: [ { relation: 'member' } ],
  where: { id: '42177991-308b-488c-b9d5-f50496d08281' } }
```

And next iteration :

```
{ include: [ { relation: 'member' } ],
  where: { and: [ [Object], [Object] ] } }
```

Is it a normal behavior that using the findById with a filter modify the filter object (by getting populated ?)or is it a bug? What should be my best options, cloning the inclusion filter everytime I want to get an object from the repository with relations ? I ran into this because after few request, my filter was too deep and loopback4 was throwing "QUERY_OBJECT_TOO_DEEP" errors.

Note: I didn't checked for other methods such as find and findOne.

Thanks for the help :) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was [a known bug](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/5814), and has been [fixed in @loopback/repository@3.4.0](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/81fab94a16f09da8d6251cef68c33b127861c0d4/packages/repository/CHANGELOG.md#340-2021-01-21).

Comment: Yep, I'm the creator of the issue (+multiple other has been related I guess) and it was fixes, thanks to the team :) !